# Propositional logic derivation

Tags: logic

Data given : Y value is either 0 or 1

Premises :

1)  $(X=Y)$$\iff$ (R $\lor$ S)

2) S $\iff$  $(X=0)$

2)  R $\implies$ $(X=1)$

Result :

$(X=1)$ $\implies$ R

Can i infer result from premises and given data ?

My $solution$ :

Since Y takes either $0 $ or $1$

(X=Y) $\iff$ $(X=0)\lor(X=1)$

then from (1)

($(X=0)$$\lor$$(X=1)$)$ \iff (R\lor S)$

substituting (2) in above equation we get

($(X=0)$$\lor$$(X=1)$)$ \iff (R\lor (X=0))$

I am taking the following propositions

P : X=$0$

Q : X=$1$
Then,

(P$\lor$Q) $\iff (R \lor P)$

I am assuming that P$\iff$~Q     (since X takes either 0 or 1)

From truth table i got

(((P$\lor$Q) $\iff (R \lor P))$ $\land$ (P$\iff$~Q)) $\implies$ ($Q \implies R$) a tautology

Then the result is a valid inference from premises and data..

Please see the proof , Is there any wrong in derivation or assumptions ? please help me.

Thank in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X = 1$, $Y = 0$, $R$ false, and $S$ is false.

(0) Then trivially $Y$ is either $0$ or $1$.

(1) $X = Y$ is false, $R \lor S$ is false, so  $X = Y \leftrightarrow R \lor S$ is true.

(2) $S$ is false and $X = 0$ are false, so $S \leftrightarrow X = 0$ is true.

(3) $R$ is false, so $R \to X = 1$ is true.

But

(4) $X = 1 \to R$ is false.

The premisses are true and conclusion false. You can't derive (4) from the given data, therefore.